# How to handle action target with the latest ember api

Tags: ember.js

In the latest documentation of Ember it's sayed that the action helper will trigger a method
on the current action.

```
   {{#if isExpanded}}
      <div class='body'>{{body}}</div>
      <button {{action "draw"}}>Draw</button>
    {{else}}
      <button {{action "expand"}}>Show More...</button>
    {{/if}}
```

How to tiggrer an action on the associated view ? I need to do some action on the view like
drawing on the canvas. But, it can't figure out how to get the reference of the view associated to current controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{{action draw target="view"}}` should work.

Comment: Thanks! It works. The documentation also say that we can handle the action in the router. Is it always possible to get the reference of the active views there ?

Comment: Yes this should be possible using the container api, but it seems an anti-pattern. Could you explain more what you would do in the question ?

Comment: In the previous version of the router we did router.get('something') to get the reference of the controller or view that we want to deal with. The question is : how to do this with the latest API ?

Comment: from an event handler in the route, you can do this.controllerFor('controllerName'), or this.container.lookup('view:viewName'). But for me this is bad smell, but if it satisfies you, use it